# Fortran 90: signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference

Tags: memory, fortran, gfortran, dynamic-arrays

The code I have written below compiles fine using GFORTRAN, however when I run the executable, the terminal window returns...

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7FC1D0F93697
#1  0x7FC1D0F93CDE
#2  0x7FC1D048E3EF
#3  0x7FC1D05AF392
#4  0x7FC1D1058360
#5  0x400CBA in MAIN__ at TRANS2DATUM.f90:?
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The code is as follows

```
PROGRAM TRANSLATE

       IMPLICIT NONE 

          REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: X(:), Y(:), Z(:)
          INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE ::  NID(:)

          REAL     MINVALUE
          INTEGER  i, NUMA

          OPEN(1,FILE='NODE_original.dat',STATUS='OLD')
          OPEN(2,FILE='NODE_trans.dat',STATUS='NEW')

10        READ(1,*,END=100)NID(i), X(i), Y(i), Z(i)

          i=i+1
          GOTO 10

100       CONTINUE
          NUMA=i

          ALLOCATE (NID(NUMA),X(NUMA),Y(NUMA),Z(NUMA))

!       Find the z value that should be zero
          MINVALUE=Z(1)
          DO i = 1, NUMA
             If ( i .EQ. 1) GOTO 11
             If (Z(i) .LE. Z(i-1)) THEN 
                  MINVALUE=Z(i)
             Else
             END IF

11           CONTINUE             
          END DO
          WRITE(*,*) "MINIMUM Z DIMENSION IS: ",MINVALUE

          IF (MINVALUE .EQ. 0) GOTO 12
          WRITE(2,*)"*NODES, NSET=NBRICK"
          DO i = 1, NUMA
             Z(i) = Z(i) - MINVALUE
             WRITE(2, 1002) NID(i), X(i), Y(i), Z(i)
          END DO 



1002     FORMAT(I10,3(",",F12.5))
12       WRITE(*,*) "ERROR: MINIUMUM VALUE ALREADY ZERO NO TRANSLATION REQUIRED"
         STOP

END PROGRAM
```

When I use this command as recommended in one of the comments below:

```
gfortran -o -g -Wall -fcheck=all  T2DATUM TRANS2DATUM.f90
```

I get the following

```
T2DATUM: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
T2DATUM: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
T2DATUM:(.rodata+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtbegin.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
T2DATUM:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
T2DATUM: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
T2DATUM: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccbWNZCJ.o: In function `main':
TRANS2DATUM.f90:(.text+0x1205): multiple definition of `main'
T2DATUM:(.text+0xc43): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
T2DATUM:(.data+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in T2DATUM(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But I have no idea what any of this means

What is causing this issue?

I am thinking it is to do with the allocatable arrays? I was hoping to use dynamic arrays because I don't have to recompile everytime I need to change the size of the arrays. Is this the best way of doing this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please compile with error checking. `gfortran -g -Wall -fcheck=all`, run again and report back. Do that always when you have an issue.

Comment: Thanks, I have done as requested please see original post

Comment: Just looking at your code, you did not allocate the arrays before reading from `NODE_original.dat`. Also, you did not initialize `i`.

Comment: Instead of `-o -g -Wall -fcheck=all  T2DATUM` you need `-o T2DATUM -g -Wall -fcheck=all`.  Your current error messages aren't relevant to your problem.

Comment: When compiled should it produce anything in the terminal?

Comment: The problem with your code is that you need to allocate the arrays before you read the data from the file. But to allocate the arrays you need to know how much data you will read. This means that you need to do the reading in two loops, first will simply count the number of lines, then you allocate memory for the arrays, and then you go through the file again to store the data in those arrays. If I get to it, I will post an answer later, but this gives you an idea what you need to do.

Comment: @PetrH We have several Qs/As about how to do that.

Comment: @VladimirF I may sound like a fool but, to understand the etiquette, what is the point you are making? No doubt there are many Qs and As on SO on this but what is the message? Does it mean that debugging questions should not have a working example as a part of the answer because those can already be found elsewhere? Since your comment was upvoted, it seems that you are telling me something important that I should know but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: @PerH You should consider whether it is worth writing a similar thing again or link to an existing question with several versions how to do that. Often the right thing is to vote to close a question as a dulicate of another one instead of answering. What is very poo taste is answering the same thing, when you already wrot that elsewhere yourself. I am not saying this question is a duplicate / should be closed (and I did not make such a vote yet). The other ones are probably not connected with a crash the OP wod not understand.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks, this makes sense, a sound advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working version with small modifications:

NODE_original.dat

```
1 2. 3. 4.
5 6. 7. 8.
9 10. 11. 12.
13 14. 15. 16.
17 18. 19. 20.
```

test.f90

```
PROGRAM TRANSLATE

       IMPLICIT NONE 

          REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: X(:), Y(:), Z(:)
          INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE ::  NID(:)

          REAL     MINVALUE
          INTEGER  i, NUMA

          ! Declare vars used for temporarily receiving
          ! the values read from the file
          REAL X_, Y_, Z_
          INTEGER :: NID_

          OPEN(1,FILE='NODE_original.dat',STATUS='OLD')
          OPEN(2,FILE='NODE_trans.dat',STATUS='NEW')

          ! i was not defined to start as zero as it should
          i=0
10        READ(1,*,END=100)NID_, X_, Y_, Z_

          i=i+1
          GOTO 10

100       CONTINUE
          NUMA=i

          ! Values were previously read but not stored.
          ! NUMA is used to allocate the arrays with the
          ! proper dimensions.
          ALLOCATE (NID(NUMA),X(NUMA),Y(NUMA),Z(NUMA))

          ! Cursor of file 1 is rewind to the beginning of
          ! the file
          REWIND(1)

          ! Read is executed for all lines with i being
          ! incremented by 1 every reading up to i=NUMA.
          ! Values are stored in the arrays at index i
          ! and can now be used as intended.
          READ(1,*)(NID(i), X(i), Y(i), Z(i), i=1,NUMA)

!       Find the z value that should be zero
          MINVALUE=Z(1)
          DO i = 1, NUMA
             If ( i .EQ. 1) GOTO 11
             If (Z(i) .LE. Z(i-1)) THEN 
                  MINVALUE=Z(i)
             Else
             END IF

11           CONTINUE             
          END DO
          WRITE(*,*) "MINIMUM Z DIMENSION IS: ",MINVALUE

          IF (MINVALUE .EQ. 0) GOTO 12
          WRITE(2,*)"*NODES, NSET=NBRICK"
          DO i = 1, NUMA
             Z(i) = Z(i) - MINVALUE
             WRITE(2, 1002) NID(i), X(i), Y(i), Z(i)
          END DO 



1002     FORMAT(I10,3(",",F12.5))
12       WRITE(*,*) "ERROR: MINIUMUM VALUE ALREADY ZERO NO TRANSLATION REQUIRED"
         STOP

END PROGRAM
```

Output:

```
:~$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

:~$ gfortran stack.f90
:~$ ./a.out 
 MINIMUM Z DIMENSION IS:    4.00000000    
 ERROR: MINIUMUM VALUE ALREADY ZERO NO TRANSLATION REQUIRED
```

Comment: It is always good to say something about those modifications. It may not be easy to identify those for someone who has to ask about the problem.

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you for the advice, I've commented the code as you suggested.